# List git branches as dynamic parameter in declarative pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Im struggeling to include a dynamic choice parameter into my declarative pipeline. I have tried lots of different suggestions from everywhere which did not really help as I've completely lost track right now :-)

For the desired functionality: I have a Jenkinsfile (declarative) for the jenkins pipeline. I want to have a parameter which allows me to choose a specific branch from a git repository to be used in the pipeline.

Basic structure of the jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {

    agent { node { label "XXX-XXX-XXX" } }

    options {
        gitLabConnection('XXX-XXX-XXX')
    }

    stages {
        stage("STAGE A") {
            parallel{
                stage("A"){
                    steps {
                        // DO STUFF
                    }
                }
                stage("B"){
                    steps {             
                        // DO STUFF
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to add a parameter using the following snippet within the pipeline. I was not able to dynamically fill the list of choices. It was either empty or it generated errors.

```
parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'CHOICE_2',
            choices: 'choice_1\nchoice_2\nchoice_3\nchoice_4\nchoice_5\nchoice_6',
            description: 'CHOICE_2 description',
        )
}
```

Alternatively I've tried to have the following outside of the pipeline declaration. I left one if the script variations in as an example. Here again, I was not able to populate the list of choices. The field stayed empty:

```
node {
    label "XXX-XXX-XXX"
    properties([
        parameters([
            [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                description: 'The names', 
                filterLength: 1, 
                filterable: true, 
                name: 'Name', 
                randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613978', 
                script: [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                    script: [
                        classpath: [], 
                        sandbox: false, 
                        script: '''
                            def gettags = "git ls-remote git@XXX-XXX-XXX.git".execute()
                            def tagList = []
                            def t1 = []
                            String tagsString = null;
                            gettags.text.eachLine {tagList.add(it)}
                            for(i in tagList)
                                t1.add(i.split()[1].replaceAll('\\^\\{\\}', ''))
                            t1 = t1.unique()
                            tagsString = StringUtils.join((String[])t1, ',');

                            return tagsString
                                '''
                    ]
                ]
            ], 
        ])
    ])
}
```

At this point I've tried too many different approaches and would like to go a step back.

Can anyone support me with an approach and some hints or ressources ?

Thanks & with best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest that you build a file with a lisf of the remote branches, aftet that you can have a stage to approve and choose the right branch - have you tried multibranch pipelines? Maybe it applies to your use case...

```
pipeline {

    agent { node { label "XXX-XXX-XXX" } }

    options {
        gitLabConnection('XXX-XXX-XXX')
        skipDefaultCheckout() //this will avoid to checkout the code by defaul
    }

    stages {
        stage("Get Branches from Git Remote"){ // you might need to tweak the list retrieved from git branches cmd
            steps{
                 withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'git-credential', passwordVariable: 'key', usernameVariable: 'gitUser')]) {    
                     sh """
                        mkdir git_check
                        cd git_check
                        git clone https://${gitUser}:${key}@${GIT_URL} .
                        git branch -a | grep remotes > ${WORKSPACE}/branchesList.txt 
                        cd ..
                        rm -r git_check
                     """
                  }
               }    
            }
        }
        stage('User Input'){
           steps{
               listBranchesAvailable = readFile 'branchesList.txt'
                    env.branchToDeploy = timeout (time:1, unit:"HOURS") {
                        input message: 'Branch to deploy', ok: 'Confirm!',
                                parameters: [choice(name: 'Branches Available:', choices: "${listBranchesAvailable }", description: 'Which branch do you want to build?')]
                        }     
           }       
        }
        stage('Checkout Code'){
            steps{
                cleanWs() // ensure workspace is empty
                git branch: "${branchToDeploy}", changelog: false, credentialsId: 'gitcredential', poll: false, url: "${GIT_URL}" //checks out the right code branch

            }
        }
        stage("STAGE A") {
            parallel{
                stage("A"){
                    steps {
                        // DO STUFF
                    }
                }
                stage("B"){
                    steps {             
                        // DO STUFF
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, 
thanks for the input. I've tried it out and it basically works. I had to embedd the part of the first stages in a script{}, but then it worked. I used git ls-remote with awk & cut in order to avoid cloning at this point. 

Multipipelines are interesting, but not that fitting for me.

One thing that still is somehow not that elegant, is the user input part. I have to select branches of multiple repositories. This way one has to reclick the current stage multiple times & jenkins doesnt handle that too well. 

But in the end it works :-)